# Re-Download the file every time I open the app

Tags: android, download, zip

My app is depends on PDF files which I download it from URL and unzip it, which works fine.
but it re-download the file.zip every time I open it even if the file is downloaded and existed.
the file size is too big so it make much trouble and hard to use.

I hope you can help
thanks alot

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


 String Url="www....zip";
 String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/unzipFolder/";
 String StorezipFileLocation =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DownloadedZip"; 
 String DirectoryName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/unzipFolder/files/";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadZipfile mew = new DownloadZipfile();
    mew.execute(Url);



class DownloadZipfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
     String result ="";
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute()
     {

      super.onPreExecute();
      mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
      mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading ... ");
      mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
      mProgressDialog.show();
     }

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... aurl)
     {
      int count;

      try
      {
           URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
           URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
           conexion.connect();
           int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
           InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

           OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(StorezipFileLocation);

           byte data[] = new byte[1024];
           long total = 0;

           while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
               {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
               }
           output.close();
           input.close();
           result = "true";
      } 

      catch (Exception e) {

       result = "false";  }
      return null;

     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
     {
      Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
      mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String unused)
     {
      mProgressDialog.dismiss();
      if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
      {
       try
       {
        unzip();
       } catch (IOException e)
       {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      else
      {

      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, onCreate() is called every time the activity is created, which happens every time you open it. You'll have to set a variable or save in a SharedPreference object whether the app should download or not. For example you could add a field `boolean isDownloaded = false` and just set that to `true` once the download has finished from within the AsyncTask.

Alternatively you can check whether the file you want to save already exists, meaning you have already saved it there before (`if((new File(path)).exists())) {...}`). However, if the download has resulted in a corrupt file, you will always keep this corrupt file if you don't take care of the issue otherwise because doing it like this will not guarantee that the download has completed successfully.

The other option I mentioned would mean to get your default `SharedPreferences` by calling `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` and using this to set and get a boolean field which tells you whether the pdf is downloaded.

The advantage with the second method is that the app will remember whether the file is downloaded even after a reboot or after completely unloading the app from memory.

Comment: that is very helpful, and works successfully , I Am using .. if((new File(path)).exists())) {...}) .. because unzip() cant unzip the file unless the file downloaded successfully, so it will be good to use.. thanks a lot ( sorry cant rating up your answer because it require 15  reputation)) ..

Answer (score 0):

Check is file exist

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

try
{

    File file = new File(StorezipFileLocation);
    if ( ! file.exists())
    {
        DownloadZipfile mew = new DownloadZipfile();
        mew.execute(Url);
    }

}
catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1)
{
}
```

Comment: ctrl-shift-o in Eclipse, to import standart libriary IOException. import java.io.IOException; It's basics...

Comment: I copy it from my working project. java.io.FileNotFoundException Added in API level 1. Subclass of java.io.IOException. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is by checking if the file exists .. File(path)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/unzipFolder/files/");
 if(f.exists() == false)
  { 
     DownloadZipfile mew = new DownloadZipfile();
     mew.execute(Url);
  }
}
```

thanks to everyone who helped or try to..

Comment: Your code same as my code. You just change StorezipFileLocation variable. I don't uderstand why you approve another answer.